Flutter OCR with google mlkit text recognizer and tesseract ocr for maintaining the same text format from image/PDF
I am developing a Flutter application where I need to recognize text from images and PDFs and maintain the same format as in the source. I am using google mlkit text recognizer and tesseract ocr  for OCR and image_picker for selecting images. However, I am facing issues in retaining the text format after recognition. The extracted text does not preserve line breaks, spacing, or formatting as in the original document.
Images for recognize :-
Image
Image
Issues:

The extracted text does not retain the original format, such as line breaks and spaces.

I need the recognized text to appear exactly as it is in the image/PDF.


Questions:

How can I modify the code to retain the formatting of the text?

Is there a better approach or library for achieving this in Flutter?


